# How do I get MarvinSketch to use the ACS style of drawing?

Tags: software

I have a Wikipedia account and the people there have a tendency for getting upset over chemical structures that I created using MarvinSketch not conforming to the ACS drawing style.

Is there any way to make MarvinSketch use the ACS drawing style?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find some information on JACS style [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aManual_of_Style_%28chemistry%29/Structure_drawing).

If you are using Marvin Sketch 5.1, first clean your structure, then got to `edit` then `format`. Click the `Apply changes for all the atoms / bonds` and then `Load Style`. Pick J. Am. Chem. Soc and `OK`.

In Marvin Sketch 6 open `File` then `Document Style` and continue as above

For more information see the documentation [here](http://www.chemaxon.com/marvin/help/sketch/sketch-basic.html#styles).

That should work

Comment: How do I set JACS as the default style? Whenever I set the style to JACS it reverts back